# How to avoid checksum files from JFrog Artifactory?

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

When I am exporting the artifacts from JFrog Artifactory using REST API. It's downloading the pom.sha256,pom.md5, pom.sha1 and jar.sha256, jar.md5, jar.sha1 (checksums). How to ignore these checksum (extra files) via Artifactory REST API?
Just want to download the .jar and .pom files.

JFrog Artifactory checksum:

[image]

Comment: Which REST API are you using to export the files?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are using the [Retrieve Folder or Repository Archive](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveFolderorRepositoryArchive) REST API, you can use the `includeChecksumFiles` parameter to control whether the exported archive includes the checksum files (default value is true).

For example:

```
curl -uadmin:password --output export.zip  http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/archive/download/libs-release-local/org?archiveType=zip&includeChecksumFiles=false
```